Visualizing 2 Layer PCB Return Currents
Hobbyist moving a manhattan-style prototype of an analog FM radio to a PCB for ease of assembly and access to SMT parts. I have attempted a 2 layer FR4 board with a 1.6mm thickness, as I feel that this emulates my working prototype of point to point islands on copper-clad fr4.
I have no experience with RF PCB design and have tried to educate myself on the topic.  This has left me little confused on some rules of thumb and isolation/emissions management.
My thought process:

Bottom layer is un-routed ground plane. Top layer is point-to-point signal and power connections.

Keep all traces short as possible, and as far away from each other as possible eg. avoid long parallel runs to minimize coupling.

Place a 1nF decoupling capacitor (circled in green) near long stretches of power trace and near amplifier/oscillator power connections. (Note: Decoupling caps in schematic do not correspond to placement in layout)


Questions:

(Excluding harmonics) If working wavelength is 88-108 MHz analog signals, then shortest lambda/10 would be 27.8 cm. None of my traces or nets are this long, though my power net is ~22cm. Do my trace impedances need any special attention? Is a PCB thickness of 1.6mm detrimental in any way?

The large pads with "RF", "LO", "Demodulate", will be air-core coils in the nH range on top of the PCB. What is the return current path for components that are above the PCB, a capacitively coupled segment on the ground plane between the pads?

There is much literature about decoupling capacitor geometry and layouts. Are those details negligible at these frequencies (88-108 MHz), eg. the green-circled capacitors will decouple as intended?

Are there any blatant intersecting return current loops? My plan to perhaps find these locations is to attach my oscilloscope ground clip to the probe tip to form an antenna and move this around the board while watching the probe FFT. I measure my oscillator frequency this way to avoid loading the tank circuit, it seems to be a usable technique at these frequencies.





You might enable (and carefully position) designators on the PCB, so that it can be traced more easily.

@TimWilliams Thanks for suggesting, I imagine that would be helpful.


Do my trace impedances need any special attention?

The 1/10 wavelength for 100MHz is ~6in on a PCB, so no if you don't have any matched sources/loads.

Is a PCB thickness of 1.6mm detrimental in any way?

If you need a matched transmission line, then yes. I don't see anything right off the bad that would warrant that.

What is the return current path for components that are above the PCB,
a capacitively coupled segment on the ground plane between the pads?

The path that high frequency currents take is the path of least impedance (resistance/inductance).
If you have a high frequency signal and a continous ground plane, then it will be directly beneath the trace.
You should use a continuous ground plane if possible. Breaking the plane will add inductance and you'll have to calculate it to see if it's a problem in your design.

the green-circled capacitors will decouple as intended?

The caps will decouple better with a continous ground plane, if it isn't continous, it will increase the inductance from cap to ground (source ground).

Thanks for answering. I was able to keep my ground plane continuous with the sole exception of vias and a 1x2 THT header in the lower right-hand corner, away from all other traces. I hope that is a decent approximation of a continuous ground plane. In terms of simulating the presence of a ground plane with a PCB thickness of 1.6mm, could I use a parallel plate capacitor calculator with two ANT-pad areas for the plates / FR4 dielectric constant and add this capacitor to LTspice to find my Q1 input impedance?
